# ASP Core 2.0 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication fails

Tags: asp.net-core, restful-authentication

I have developed a web application using dot net core 1.1. It was working fine till I've updated to asp core 2.0. Then when trying to use the application, it reports this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

The authentication config of JwtBearerAuthentication, in the `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` was previously like bellow:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });
```

After facing this error I have updated that to this one:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
            AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        });
```

But still the error message is alive. Am I looking wrong place for the error or I have have to add additional configurations for the authentication system to work?

Comment: Authentication was changed in 2.0. More info here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262

Comment: TL;DR: Only middleware needed is `app.UseAuthentication();` and you define authentication handlers as services in `ConfigureServices()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just followed this article and everything goes perfect.

[Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

Hope it helps other.

TG.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead of your own code to solve your problem:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
     JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
     JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
```